# Ruby On Rails - Zurb Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zurb-foundation, grid-layout, skip

If I want to skip some of the components zurb foundation offers, how do I do this?

Example:
I only want to use the grid system.

```
rails g foundation:install --skip=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just require the needed parts inside your application js and css files

```
//= require foundation.name
```

However, the grid doesn't seem to be inside a special package.

Checkout the rails gem for more details.
It does seem that you can load the grid css file, might wanna try that out

```
*= require foundation.components.grid
```